# Changing resource target dir in gradle built jar

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube

I have the following structure in the project:

Project_1 -> src->main->java->all_java_files
          -> src->main->resources-> all_prop_files

I want to build the jar so that the property files will be put under 'main/resources' inside the jar. By default gradle puts them under root.

Here is my build file with my fix. But this causes sonarqube indexing issues.Is there an easy way to change output directory for the resource files?:

apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {

```
compile libraries.log4j
compile libraries.apache_commons_net
compile libraries.apache_commons_lang2

compile libraries.apache_velocity
compile libraries.ehcache_15    
compile libraries.apache_commons_validator

compile libraries.apache_xmlbeans

compile libraries.spring_framework
```

}

compileJava.classpath += was70ServerLibraryJars

sourceSets {

```
main {  
    resources{
            srcDirs = ['src']
            exclude 'main/java'

        }
}
```

}

jar {

}

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you move

src->main->resources-> all_prop_files

to

src->main->resources->main->resources-> all_prop_files

By convention everything in src/main/resources will be copied in the root of the JAR.